# Can someone tell me what's wrong with this javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am trying something experimental here, please answer, what's wrong in this code?

```
function run(){
 for(var i=0;i<arguments.length;i++){
  var type=arguments[i].split(" ")[0];
   if(type=="(write)"){
    var arr=arguments[i].split(" ");
    var str=[];
    for(var i=1;i<arr.length;i++){
     str.push(arr[i]);
    }
    var fin="\n"+str.join(" ");
    document.getElementById("console").textContent+=fin;
   }
  }
 }
run(
 "(write) I wonder if this works.",
 "(write) I think it DOES!"
);
```

Somehow it only puts "I wonder if this works." in the div but no "I think it DOES!". Can someone tell me what's wrong and return the corrected script?

Comment: You’re using `i` twice. Tools like [JSHint](http://jshint.com/) can tell you that.

Comment: oh. thanks. im not working on a fancy program so... ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript does not have block scope.. change your other var i to something else

Comment: Javascript has block scope with let and const, so its wrong to say that Javascript does not have block scope

Answer (score 0):

You are using i variable of for loop twice.
Javascript has functional scope and block scope.
So use different variable in second "for" (may be a j);

```
for(var j=1;j<arr.length;j++){
     str.push(arr[j]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function run(){


  for(var i=0;i<arguments.length;i++){


    var type=arguments[i].split(" ")[0];
    if(type=="(write)"){
      var arr=arguments[i].split(" ");

      var str=[];

      //here your i was increamented twice so loop excuted only once
      for(var j=1;j<arr.length;j++){
       str.push(arr[j]);
     }


     var fin="\n"+str.join(" ");
     console.log(fin);
     document.getElementById("console").textContent+=fin;
   }
 }
}
run(
 "(write) I wonder if this works.",
 "(write) I think it DOES!"
 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `i` in loop in:

```
for (var i = 1; i < arr.length; i++){
    str.push(arr[i]);
}
```

by something else or use let in es6 to define i.